# Android widget xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, widget

I created a simple widget and when I am trying to run it, I get this kind of exception:

```
Parameter name: Type is not derived from a java type.(this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType (typeof (WordWidget)).Name
```

Code is:

```
[Service]
public class UpdateService : Service
{
    public override void OnStart (Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        RemoteViews updateViews = buildUpdate (this);
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName (this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType (typeof (WordWidget)).Name);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.GetInstance (this);
        manager.UpdateAppWidget (thisWidget, updateViews);
    }
```

Comment: I can easily run [this sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/SimpleWidget/UpdateService.cs) which is very similar to your code. Have you tried comparing your own code with the sample from Xamarin?

Comment: So could I, but in my project it brings me exception as I mentioned above. As I understood, I need somehow to implement Java.Lang.Class.

Comment: Could you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I realized that my WordWidget class didn't inherit AppWidgetProvider android class. So now it works.

Comment: @Vitali Glad to know you solved your issue. It may make sense to post your comment as the accepted answer. This will make the life easier for others whom may also stumble into this issue.

Comment: @Demitrian do you know maybe how can i dinamically populate custom rows in widget? Examples only show how to work with listview and not with remoteview.